# Trying to get a web application with a database online? Really Struggling

Tags: mysql, database, web-services, amazon-web-services, wamp

I apologize in advance if any part of my question seems really stupid.
I am an undergraduate student. I don't have any experience in website development but the research I am doing this summer involves a lot of it so I have taught myself some stuff.

I have built a web application that functions like a survey. A person starts taking the survey, their ID is stored in the database and their responses are recorded an analyzed. The application that I built on my local computer is fully functional and now I am trying to get it online so it can be accessed by the public. So far I have created a series of .php files on my local computer and I am using WAMP server and I have a functional database all set up on PhpMyadmin. My web application with the .php files and database works. All files can be run successfully and the database is successfully being accessed and updated.

I am trying to get this online for free if possible. I am currently using a free trial of Amazon Web Services which is free for a couple months (since the application is a survey it does not need to be online longer than that) but it is really confusing me. Amazon Web services' how-to guides involve writing additional .NET files and creating a whole series of instances of virtual servers in the cloud. I have no idea what I'm doing and there must be a simple way to put up a very basic web application written solely in php, javascript, html and CSS with a simple Mysqlite database on the backend. Any ideas? I am really strapped for time so any help would be oh so greatly appreciate :):):)

Thank you!!

Comment: use your machine (if it's a desktop).  It already runs on your machine; if you're on a campus network your ports may already be open.  if you live off-campus get a free hostname and point it at your ip address.  then you can access it from anywhere.  aka, amazon web services is entirely unnecessary for what you are doing, from what i can tell

Comment: You have a fine question, but in the future, avoid the "Really Struggling", "I apologize in advance", etc and focus on building a clearer, shorter and objective question, that helps a lot in getting answers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to start a new micro windows server (a.k.a EC2 instance) in your free tier and use the same WAMP server that you are already used to. See how to start a windows instance here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/EC2Win_GetStarted.html

When launching the instance, remember to open the HTTP port in the "security group" section of the launch wizard.

Then, if you need, you can use other AWS services to build a more robust configuration, such as a separate database server using RDS, deployment using Elastic Beanstalk, storage on S3 and many other services.